# Autofac Property Injection after a type is Registered

Tags: c#, autofac

Im using autofac 3(latest version)

How to do Property Injection after the Type got registered in the builder i.e.

builder.RegisterType(customType);

Now I want to inject property information into customType.

I dont want to do it at the time of Initialization.

Is there a way to do that ?

---

I want it to be done in 2 steps :
step - 1:
Register the component

step - 2:
Extract the registered Component and then Inject the Property Value Pair into that Registration.

Is it possible with autofac ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'property information'?

Comment: Suppose there is a property by name "Title" in that class, I would like to set it to some string value after initialization.

Comment: I have a similar requirement, I couldn't find a way. Following your question for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WithProperty` or `WithProperties` methods if you want to set the injections at registration rather than at initialization.

ie `builder.RegisterType(customType).WithProperty("PropertyName", "value");`

Comment: That feature is not available in autofac3 , Moreover I dont want to re-register my type. I want to get hold of my previous registration and then inject dependencies into it.